# Custom Cellular Automata rule with k colors

Tags: cellular-automata

How can I use the CellularAutomaton function to create a 2D automaton using a custom function and k colors?

I understood from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326620/create-a-new-cellular-automata-rule-in-mathematica) how to use custom rules for 1D automata.

I'm trying now to do that for 2D automata but I don't quite understand how CellularAutomaton is reacting to this.

I tried this to see what the general function gets:

```
CellularAutomaton[{Print[#] &, {}, {1, 1}}, {{{1}}, 0}, 1]
```

And I see that I get a matrix representing, I assume, the possible cases for rules

[image]

Compare this to the 1D case

[image]

But I still don't completely understand how to interpret this matrix and how to use more colors.

My final goal is to create [this kind of cyclic automata](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/papers/cca.pdf) using the CellularAutomaton function

Any kind of help would be useful. Thanks

Comment: Can you put more information? I mean what is the input of your function and how you plotted it?

Comment: @wandermonde I solved it. The approved answer is the one I did. About the input, it's just an implementation of this paper (https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/papers/cca.pdf). To plot it it's just an ArrayPlot

Comment: @wandermondeI'm actually working on a computational essay about this. It's not ready yet (and will probably be posted in the Wolfram Community). Once it's done I can let you know here. If you have other questions please let me know.

Comment: @wandermonde You can see other preliminary CCA work I did here: https://wolfr.am/MSTvSyVA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it. It's probably not the best implementation but works. Any feedback about how to optimize the code would be highly appreciated.

```
CyclicFunction[N_,matrix_,preylist_]:=Module[{cell=matrix[[2,2]],prey},prey=preylist[cell];If[MemberQ[Flatten[matrix],prey],prey,cell]]

CyclicCellularAutomaton[k_,size_,steps_]:=With[{preylist=Association@@Function[u,u-> RotateLeft[Range[0,k-1],u][[2]]]/@Range[0,k-1]},CellularAutomaton[{CyclicFunction[k,#,preylist]&,{},{1,1}},RandomInteger[{0,k-1},size],{{{steps}}}]]
```

BTW, I exported the evolution of the automaton as a gif but doesn't loop infinitely...why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Every possible 2D function is enumerated in `CellularAutomaton`, so you need merely pick the function number.  To get your desired colors, use `ColorFunction`, e.g.,

```
ArrayPlot[
 CellularAutomaton[{746, 
     {2, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}, 
     {1, 1}}, 
     {{Table[1, {7}]}, 0}, {{{150}}}],
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

or

```
ColorRules -> {0 -> Red, 1 -> Green, _ -> Black}
```

If you want to write your own function, look at the documentation for `CellularAutomaton` to see examples, such as:

```
CellularAutomaton[{Total[#] &, {}, 1/2}, {{1}, 0}, 5] // Grid
```

Comment: How do you go from an arbitrary function to a function number? I want to write my own function, i.e. using the rule form {fun,{},rspec}

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I already know how to write my own function for 1D. What I'm asking is how to do that for 2D automata. Examples in the ref pages are for 1D